# MC34063 used as boost converter

Tags: power-supply

I'm designing 12V to 170V power supply using MC34063 for testing. LTSpice simulation works, but when I assembled it on breadboard, it switches at first, but after that, it stops. Does somebody have any suggestions? For the diode I use MUR120.

[image]

Comment: How does the peak current in your LTspice simulation compare with the saturation current of your (real) 180uH inductor ?  12:170 is a bit high for a boost converter.

Comment: Saturation current for inductor is 1.8A. LTspice simulation of inductors peak current is 7,2A for 400uS. But I used TI applications note for calculation, and after calculating it was enough. Also i agree, 12 to 170V is a bit high, since efficency suffers, but it should still work.

Comment: Breadboard you say? Switching converters are notoriously difficult to run on breadboards. Show your “layout”.

Comment: Added pictures of my "layout".

Comment: What switching frequency are you employing?... OK, 50 kHz.

Comment: Yeah, and maximum allowed frequency is 100kHz, so it is within specification.

Comment: Your potential divider suggests it should regulate at 150 volts. Have you tried operating it at a lower voltage and, have you tried with a more substantial load on the output? Also you said this: *it switches at first, but after that, it stops* <-- over what timescale was that observation?

Comment: I haven't tried it with lower voltage , but tried with different loads, and no difference. . Since i don't have oscilloscope in my hands at the moment, I can not anwser that question, will observe it tomorrow, also try lower voltages.

Comment: You really need a low ESR film or ceramic capacitor for high frequency bypass on Vcc. And you might try cleaning and scrubbing the board with alcohol, followed by detergent, and finally clean water rinse and heat gun or oven.

Comment: Data sheet shows 40V as max switch collector voltage... with your design, are you perhaps driving the voltage on that node too high and that transistor is breaking down?

Comment: Why wouldn't you use the ISNS feature? (And I use "feature" lightly; MC34063 is a VERY primitive SMPS chip. I strongly recommend at least using the improved NCP3063, but better still a UC3843 or LM3481.)

Comment: Please add the technical details in your comments to your question if you want to get an answer.  Having to dig through comments is a pain, especially as replies to concerns highlighted by others,

Comment: Connect SWC to VCC, not to the inductor.

Answer (score 1):

So yes, silly mistake, I'm driving collector with 150V. Probably fried the chip.

Comment: Where did the remaining 20 Volts go?

Comment: @greybeard Wrong voltage divider resistances.